# html file input get full path with pyqt5

Tags: python, file, input, path, pyqt5

I'm using pyqt to build the gui of my desktop app with html. I want to browse for a file with `<input type="file">` and need the full path to process this file on backend side but i read about a security vulnerability and it seems to be not possible as far as i know.

I don't want to upload the file (the file will have a size of 4GB), I only need the path as string to send it to backend via QWebChannel and run some python code.

I currently can't find a solution to do this, can someone help me?

Thats how some of my gui part is looking like:
[image]

**EDIT**
Found a nice solution. I do a e.preventdefault() in my JS function and call a method on the backend side where i call `name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', '', '', '')`.
Then i return the selected file back to my JS function and put it into the input field.
Also i found out how to use developer tools of the Webengine.

(Py)Qt is so amazing!!

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible. Is there a good reason to use a website as frontend instead of using Qt Widgets or QML?

Comment: Sure, i have no limitations in building my gui and I'm so much more familar with html than Qt widgets or QML

Comment: found a nice solution